# Enviar un archivo/imagen con html a travez de Correo

Tags: php, html, email

Mi consulta es la siguiente, me encargaron un sitio web el cual pueda mandar correos con mensajes de confirmación para eventos, el tema es que en el mensaje debe ir un código qr, con eso no hay problema todo bien hasta ahí, pero cuando tengo que mandar una imagen no puedo hacerlo, estoy usando la API de **SendingBlue** para esto, pero cuando envió la imagen no se visualiza en el correo. No se me ocurre cómo podría hacerlo, me gustaría quizás poder adjuntarlo, pero si es posible que aparezca en el cuerpo del correo seria mejor.

```
function enviarCorreo($rut,$id)
{
    $con = conectarBD();
    $credentials = SendinBlue\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('api-key', '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');
    $apiInstance = new SendinBlue\Client\Api\TransactionalEmailsApi(new GuzzleHttp\Client(), $credentials);

    #foreach ($rut as $identificador) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE rut = '$rut'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    $sendSmtpEmail = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\SendSmtpEmail([
        'subject' => 'Correo Numero 1',
        'sender' => ['name' => 'GROW', 'email' => 'c.aros10@alumnos.santotomas.cl'],
        'replyTo' => ['name' => 'GROW', 'email' => 'c.aros10@alumnos.santotomas.cl'],
        'to' => [['name' => $row['nombre'] . $row['apellido1'], 'email' => $row['correo']]],
        'htmlContent' => '
        <html>
        <body>
        <h1>Este es un correo de prueba</h1>
        {{params.bodyMessage}}
        '.crearQR($id).'
        </body>
        </html>',
        'params' => ['bodyMessage' => 'Hola estoy probando los correos']
    ]);

    try {
        $result = $apiInstance->sendTransacEmail($sendSmtpEmail);
        print_r($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
    # }

    $con->close();
}

function crearQR($id)
{
    include("../phpqrcode/qrlib.php");

    $con = conectarBD();

    //Busqueda de email y contraseña en la base de datos
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM evento_historial WHERE evento_historial.id_historial_evento = $id";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

    //Exportamos una imagen con el codigo QR
    QRcode::png($row['id_historial_evento'] . $row['id_cliente_rut_fk'] . $row['id_evento_fk'], "../CodigosQR/".$row['id_historial_evento'] . $row['id_cliente_rut_fk'] . "qr.png", "L", 4, 4);

    //Mostramos la imagen
    return '<img src="../CodigosQR/'.$row['id_historial_evento'].$row['id_cliente_rut_fk'].'qr.png" alt=No se encontro la imagen/>';

}
```

Comment: Por curiosidad, esta función: `QRcode::png` ¿genera el archivo en la ubicación `../CodigosQR/` ?

Comment: Y si la envía dentro del mensaje? Total, la imagen ya esta alojada en algún lugar y tiene una url, porque no hacer que se vea en el correo como una imagen dentro de un <img> ??

Comment: ¿Probaste con mailtrap?